# Predicting estimated time of arrival (ETA) with custom loss function

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, loss-functions, poisson-regression

I have an assignment of ETA prediction that I'd like to seek some advice from you. I need to train a model from a dataset to predict ETA of parcels as dependent variable, which is discrete (in days). There are some features such as distance, parcel type, etc. And one requirement of this question is that customers are not happy if their parcels are delayed, so actual arrival time > predicted ETA is unfavorable.

Here I have 2 questions:

1. Shall I assume Poisson distribution of ETA and use a Poisson regressor or shall I just apply some standard regression model?
2. Given delay is unfavorable, I understand I need to use some custom loss function to penalize negative error, but I'm struggling on what kind of loss function to use? Anyone can share some insights?

Thank you!